# Wiring a Westinghouse 312P787 electric motor

Tags: wiring

I have an electric motor, Westinghiouse 312P787 3/4 HP Single phase 115/230 volt 1725/1140 RPM with a start capacitor. I would like to use it to run my drill press.  There is no wiring diagram and I've looked for one extensively.  Right now it runs with a hand turn and gets very hot very quickly so I haven't tried it with a load. The capacitor is good but I'm sure I have it wired incorrectly.There are a total of 6 wires coming out, 4 from the lead end, black, red, blue and green, and 2 black wires from the capacitor housing. My application is for 110 volt. I'm not an electrician but I have a good respect for the dangers of electricity and feel I'm comfortable repairing most electrical items.  This is my first motor, however.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and I thank you in advance for your help and time.

Comment: Stop guessing.  This is mains power, not to be fooled with.  Can you post a photo of the motor's nameplates?

Comment: Are there any numbers on the wires ?

Comment: That's going to be tough without the manufacturer's wiring diagram. 2 speed you can find easily, dual voltage you can find easily, but 2 speed AND dual voltage is not in any standard wiring diagram books I have. Did you look on the inside of the connection box for a diagram?